# Mongodb geoNear ignores maxDistance

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing an endpoint which responds with the nearest destinations within a radius along with the distance for given co-ordinates. I am using node for the same with ***mongodb v2.4*** as the data store. All the location data is stored in GeoJson format and 2dsphere index is created on the collection.

```
db.dest.geoNear(lon,lat,
                {num: 30, maxDistance: 20000, query: {someQuery for filtering}
                , spherical: true, distanceMultiplier: 6378.1}
                , function(err, results){})
```

The maxDistance is given in meters as stated in the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/command/geoNear/#dbcmd.geoNear) and distanceMultiplier being radius of earth. But somehow the maxDistance is being ignored. Below is the sample output

```
{ results:
   [ { dis: 4.755328392420995, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 4.807060479634336, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 5.492899524461121, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 5.511199055273086, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 5.511199055273086, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 5.660463080160375, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 5.682780578954481, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 5.803407121966422, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 5.89496185238861, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 5.912218148470887, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 6.043122792876154, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 6.138052836083365, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 6.152973556017727, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 6.895647639041904, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 7.487292026198752, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 7.487292026198752, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 8.18958659411917, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 8.18958659411917, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 8.18958659411917, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 116.1262295642328, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 197.59476541200738, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 281.1553130990714, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 293.0284376976589, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 293.0961663596255, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 293.10437722899286, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 293.3819790311049, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 293.5152536606294, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 293.5332617516882, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 293.5546344697255, obj: [Object] },
     { dis: 294.7790206142557, obj: [Object] } ],
  stats:
   { nscanned: 470,
     objectsLoaded: 470,
     avgDistance: 102.08913656122567,
     maxDistance: 294.7790206142557,
     time: 37 },
  ok: 1 }
```

As you can see the trailing entries are out of the 20 km radius. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Units  are a mess when using `$geoNear`, but it looks like the call has everything right. Can you reduce this to a reproducible example? Just take 2-3 documents, some that should be returned, some that shouldn't, and show us the docs and the query that returns docs it shouldn't. Right now we can't see the data, which could have a bad format.

Comment: are you missing a comma? maxDistance: 20000 query: should there be a comma after 20000 and before query?

Comment: @Alex: I think that was typo. I figured it out. Even thought the docs say that the maxDistance has to be in meters, when I provided it in radians, the query started working.

Comment: @guarav feel free to answer your own question, may help others :)